# noAdajacentDuplicates using a stack

Tags: java, arrays, set, stack

I've been struggling with this portion of a program where I need to achieve the following.

3. “Elimination of Adjacent Duplicates”:

a.  given an array of integers create ArrayList that contains all the numbers remaining after eliminating all adjacent duplicates in one pass using one stack

b.  analyze sample runs

c.  describe the algorithm in pseudocode

d.  implement and test

e.  You may only use one loop.

Sample Run:

```
*** ELIMINATING ADJACENT DUPLICATES ***
--> testcase #1
input = [1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = [1] CORRECT

---> testcase #2
input = [1, 9, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = [1, 9, 5] CORRECT

---> testcase #3
input = [1, 1, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = [5] CORRECT

---> testcase #4
input = [1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = [] CORRECT
Done!
```

Here is my code, but I'm using two loops because this was the only way I could find to make the code work. Is there any tips you guys would have for getting rid of that second loop? Or should I just scrap this all together and use a different algorithm?

```
public ArrayList<Integer> noAdjacentDuplicates(int... input)
{
    // TODO PROJECT #1 - Complete
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

    System.out.println("input = " + Arrays.toString(input));
    int loop = input.length - 1; //initialize array index

            while(loop >= 0)
            {
                if(!stack.empty())
                {
                    int topElement = stack.peek();

                    if(topElement == input[loop])
                    {
                        while(loop >= 0 && input[loop] == topElement){loop--;}
                        stack.pop();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stack.push(input[loop]);
                        loop--;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    stack.push(input[loop]);
                    loop--;
                }
            }

    while(!stack.empty())
    {
        result.add(stack.pop());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: input = [1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = [1]
How are 5,6,0 eliminated even without adjacent duplicates?

Comment: With my level of knowledge, I feel your code is good enough.

Comment: @RohanDs the way this algorithm works is a little funky, but when you delete the numbers in the middle it re-evaluates the duplicates as such.
[1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
[1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 6, 5]
[1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 6, 5]
[1, 5, 6, 6, 5]
[1, 5, 5]
[1]

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code so that it will only use 1 loop as this suggests.

> e. You may only use one loop.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

    public static String[] array = new String[5];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] input = { 1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5 };
        System.out.println("input = " + Arrays.toString(input));
        ArrayList<Integer> result = noAdjacentDuplicates(input);
        System.out.println("result = " + result.toString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        input = new int[] { 1, 9, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5 };
        System.out.println("input = " + Arrays.toString(input));
        result = noAdjacentDuplicates(input);
        System.out.println("result = " + result.toString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        input = new int[] { 1, 1, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5 };
        System.out.println("input = " + Arrays.toString(input));
        result = noAdjacentDuplicates(input);
        System.out.println("result = " + result.toString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        input = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5 };
        System.out.println("input = " + Arrays.toString(input));
        result = noAdjacentDuplicates(input);
        System.out.println("result = " + result.toString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        input = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
        System.out.println("input = " + Arrays.toString(input));
        result = noAdjacentDuplicates(input);
        System.out.println("result = " + result.toString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        input = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 2 };
        System.out.println("input = " + Arrays.toString(input));
        result = noAdjacentDuplicates(input);
        System.out.println("result = " + result.toString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        input = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
        System.out.println("input = " + Arrays.toString(input));
        result = noAdjacentDuplicates(input);
        System.out.println("result = " + result.toString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> noAdjacentDuplicates(int[] input) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        boolean hasAdjacent = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            int value = input[i]; // get current value
            if (stack.isEmpty()) { // if stack is empty then just push the value
                stack.push(value);
                result.add(value);
            } else {
                int top = stack.peek(); // get the top of the stack
                if (value == top) { // if current value is equal to the top of the stack meaning it has an adjacent
                    hasAdjacent = true;
                }
                // if value is not equal to top but it has an adjacent before
                // example [8, 8, 8, 1], this will trigger on the current value is 1
                else if (value != top && hasAdjacent) {
                    stack.pop(); // pop the stack
                    result.remove(result.size() - 1); // remove the head of the list
                    hasAdjacent = false; // revert has adjacent to false since it starts a new value
                }

                // this checking is required inorder to know if the current value is the same as
                // the top of the stack
                if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    top = stack.peek();
                }

                // check if the value is equal to the new top of the stack
                // example [1, 0, 0, 2], the cursor is currently at the last value of 1
                // the stack contains [1, 0], the 0 will be deleted in the elseif above,
                // the new top of the stack is 1 and the value is 2, thus you should add the
                // value in the stack and in the list
                if (value != top && !hasAdjacent) {
                    stack.push(value);
                    result.add(value);
                }
                // example [1, 0, 0, 1], the cursor is currently at the last value of 1
                // the stack contains [1, 0], the 0 will be deleted in the elseif above,
                // the new top of the stack is 1 and the value is 1, thus you should pop the
                // stack and remove the head of the list
                else if (value == top && !hasAdjacent) {
                    stack.pop();
                    result.remove(result.size() - 1);
                }
            }

            // System.out.println(stack); // Uncomment this line so that you'll see the
            // movement of the stack
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Output

```
input = [1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = [1]
----------------------------------
input = [1, 9, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = [1, 9, 5]
----------------------------------
input = [1, 1, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = [5]
----------------------------------
input = [1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 5]
result = []
----------------------------------
input = [1, 0, 0, 1]
result = []
----------------------------------
input = [1, 0, 0, 2]
result = [1, 2]
----------------------------------
input = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
result = [1]
----------------------------------
```

Comment: @Fishayyy Your welcome. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer so that this question will be marked as solved.